# How do you include css and javascript in rails mountable engine (3.1.3) ? When do we use application.css and application.js exactly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using rails 3.1.3 and making a mountable engine. I placeed the css files in app/assets/stylesheets/(projectnameindowncase)/
and similarly placed the javascript files in app/assets/javascripts/(projectnameindowncase)/

I did not explicitly add the refrences to the stylesheets/javascripts assuming it is taken care of (that's what i had read). Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this resource: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html.

I think you most likely need to include a:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

tag in your application.html.erb file. This brings in the application.js(.coffee) file, which compiles all of your other javascript into it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had included <%= javascript_include_tag "NMC/application" %> in the application.html.erb but still it seems to be ignoring it.

Comment: What does the top of your application.js file look like?

Comment: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

Comment: and what exactly was the code in your head element to include the javascript files?

Comment: do we need to explicitly include the javascript files in the head even after aaplication.js tells us that all the javascripts in all the subdirectories will be available to the whole directory?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. what exactly is the code in the head element? You should post it in your original question.

Comment: It seems rails does not accept the module name nmc and was acting weird. The moment i changed the project name to something else it worked perfectly !!

Comment: btw Why is it that every scaffolding i generate also generates a respective css? Do we have to code the css part of a controller in a respective css having same name as controller?

Comment: You don't have to, but that's the "Rails Way" of keeping your code organized.

Answer (score 0):

Or add them manually to the precompile directive under config/environments/*

```
 config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
```

Comment: But aren't the js and css files supposed to be automatically minified and made into a single css/js file accordingly?

Comment: Not sure, but according to [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) **If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript files to include, you can add them to the precompile array**

Comment: No, they're not automatically added, unless they're (even deep) included in the application.js/application.css

Answer (score 0):

The standard rails convention is to have (only) one application.js and one application.css included in your layout. All dependencies declared in that file are automatically precompiled.

Unfortunately, the `require_tree` sprockets command that is by default in these files does not seem to work over engines, so the best thing to do is to add them manually in the project's application files.

It seems to be good practice to do that in the install generator of the mountable engine, where you can do the mounting itself as well.